# Merge multiple column into one column as list in python pandas

Tags: pandas

How to create a new column [ColumnA] and store data as list instead of string?
I need to loop data for processing later on based on index using REST API POST method.

```
            Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  ColumnA
    Index
0       a        1        2        3        4  [1,2,3,4]
1       a        3        4        5      NaN    [3,4,5]
2       b        6        7        8      NaN    [6,7,8]
3       c        7        7      NaN      NaN      [7,7]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clear of `MultiIndex` or `Index` in input Data, so number of levels is counted by `range`:

```
df['ColumnA'] = df.stack().astype(int).groupby(level=list(range(df.index.nlevels))).agg(list)
print (df)
         Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4       ColumnA
  Index                                                  
0 a            1        2      3.0      4.0  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1 a            3        4      5.0      NaN     [3, 4, 5]
2 b            6        7      8.0      NaN     [6, 7, 8]
3 c            7        7      NaN      NaN        [7, 7]
```

Or:

```
df['ColumnA'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().astype(int).tolist(), axis=1)
```

If there are empty strings:

```
print (df)
         Column1  Column2 Column3 Column4
  Index                                  
0 a            1        2     3.0     4.0
1 a            3        4     5.0        
2 b            6        7     8.0        
3 c            7        7               

df['ColumnA'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x!= ''].astype(int).tolist(), axis=1)

print (df)
         Column1  Column2 Column3 Column4       ColumnA
  Index                                                
0 a            1        2     3.0     4.0  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1 a            3        4     5.0             [3, 4, 5]
2 b            6        7     8.0             [6, 7, 8]
3 c            7        7                        [7, 7]
```

Comment: Both works!  Thank you.   Follow up question, why this statement add '' for each value inside the list?   `print(df.loc['c', ['ColumnA']].values[0])`

Comment: @hanna - there are missing values or empty strings?

Comment: @jezrael   It returns  `['7','7']` instead of `[7,7]`

Comment: @hanna - solutions was edited for integers.

Comment: Strange, if I loop, I don't get single qoute.   `pm = df.loc['c', ['ColumnA']].values[0]`
    print(pm) `['7','7']`
    for x in pm:
        print(x)
`7 7`

Comment: @hanna - added `.astype(int)` and still not working? Weird

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232937/discussion-between-hanna-and-jezrael).